# Propel2 collections disappear on update

Tags: symfony, collections, propel, propel2

My colleagues and I have written a dozen web applications using Symfony2 and Propel1. We are now trying to use Propel2 but encounter the following problem when migrating an application from Propel1 to Propel2.

In our simple schema, a parent object, `Auteur` (author) possesses a collection of children `Livre` (book) objects. We use a Symfony form to create the `Auteur` with a collection of `Livres` objects. In this case, the `Auteur` and `Livres` are correctly persisted in the database.

However, **when we *update* the `Auteur` object without touching the collection of `Livres`, the collection is emptied**.

We could not determine whether this was a bug in Propel2 (or less probably Symfony2) or if we are doing things incorrectly.
The almost same code (somewhat adapted to Propel1) works without a problem: the `Livres` collection is *not* emptied on `Auteur` update.

We have published a minimal project reproducing the problem. To test it with Propel2, please do:

```
git clone https://github.com/spyrit/MinimalS2P2.git
cd MinimalS2P2
composer install
app/console propel:build
app/console propel:migration:diff
app/console propel:migration:migrate
```

To test it with *Propel1*, use to the `propel1` branch:

```
git checkout propel1
composer install
app/console propel:build
app/console propel:migration:generate-diff
app/console propel:migration:migrate
```

We will be grateful on any hint concerning this issue.

Comment: We think more and more that it must be a Propel2 bug: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach was correct, but there was a bug in Propel2 that caused this issue.

It was fixed in https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/pull/1027